# Dictionary error while passing a class in to a cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dictionary

I was trying to pass 2 classes in to the one cshtml file and kept getting an error I was passing a model "of type 'JavaTutorial.Models.Quiz', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'JavaTutorial.Models.Evaluation'."

I don't get it, I'm after creating a seperate class and am now just trying to pass in one class but still the error appears.

I have a class Evaluation to which I'm trying to call upon in the cshtml but a Quiz class keeps interfering but I have no idea why..

```
cshtml:

    @model JavaTutorial.Models.Evaluation

<h2>Details</h2>
<h2>Evaluation</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Evaluation.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace JavaTutorial.Models
{
    public class Evaluation
    {
        public List<Question> Questions { set; get; }
        public Evaluation()
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>();
        }
    }

}
```

Quiz.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace JavaTutorial.Models
{
    public class Quiz
    {
        [Key]
        public int QuizId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int difficulty { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public List<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
        [Required]
        public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }
        public Question()
        {
            Answers = new List<Answer>();
        }
    }
    public class Answer
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; }
    }
   /* public class Evaluation
    {
        public List<Question> Questions { set; get; }
        public Evaluation()
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>();
        }
    }*/

    /*public class ParentView
    {
        public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
        public Question Question { get; set; }
        public Answer Answer { get; set; }
        public Evaluation Evaluation{ get; set; }

    }
    */


    /*
     * using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Evaluation.Questions)
    <input type="submit" />
}*/
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using JavaTutorial.Models;
//using ViewModels;


namespace JavaTutorial.Controllers
{
    public class QuizController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Quiz/

        TutorialEntities storeDB = new TutorialEntities();



        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var quiz = storeDB.Quizzes.Find(id);
            return View(quiz);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set model in view:

```
@model JavaTutorial.Models.Evaluation
```

but you are not passing this model:

```
JavaTutorial.Models.Quiz
```

View expects the Model Class **Evaluation** but you are passing **Quiz** class

If you want to pass Quiz Model change in View like this:

```
@model JavaTutorial.Models.Quiz
```

If you want to pass two models, create a **viewmodel** and it in a folder named **ViewModels** in your solution.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
public List<Question> Questions { set; get; }
public List<Quiz> Quizzes{ set; get; }
public List<Answer> Asnwers { set; get; }
}
```

ans pass thie view model to your view and set in view like this:

```
@model JavaTutorial.ViewModels.MyViewModel
```

Comment: I'm trying to just pass Evaluation, why is it looking for Quiz?

Comment: because you are passing quiz object to view.